# Почему приложение, написанное на C# 4.0, на Windows XP использует только одно ядро и не видит другие?

Tags: c#, windows, многопоточность

Добрый вечер. Мне на работе дали задание написать программу читающую данные с COM- порта и выводящую на экран график. Я ее отлаживал на моем ноутбуке с Intel Core i3 M380 и все было вроде бы нормально - всё отрисовывалось, ничего особо не тупило.
Но как только я ее запустил на целевом панельном компьютере с Intel Atom D525, у меня все дико затормозило! Я посмотрел нагрузку ЦП, а там на 100% грузится только одно ядро, а три других в простое. Я не пойму никак, в чем беда? У меня на ноутбуке работа как-то распределялась по ЦП, хотя я и не использовал библиотеку Task Parallel, а только стандартные BackgroundWorker, всё равно все было нормально, а на том панельном просто пипец что. У менясроки горят, подскажите пожалуйста что делать/
Я уж извернулся как мог: данные с порта кидаются в очереди и вынимаются оттуда раз в 100 мс, затем делаетcя синхронный вызов делегата

```
chartDelegate.EndInvoke(chartDelegate.BeginInvoke(args, null, null))
```

и переданные значения добавляются в график

```
for (int i=0; i < date.Lenght; i++)
{
chart1.Series["Main"].Point.AddXY(date[i], var1[i]);
}
```

И по сути всё. Но программа начинает настолько тупить, что не прорисовывается ни один Control, кроме chart'a, а сам chart рисуется с дикой задержкой

Структура программы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так откуда у вас возьмется распределение по ядрам если вы в один поток все делаете?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, у вас самая тяжелая операция - отрисовка диаграммы, а она-то как раз делается в потоке UI.

Comment: Ну почему в одном потоке? У меня 10 BackgroundWorkeroв. 9 из них синхронизируются с собой через Eventы, а один делает синхронные вызовы к главному

Comment: Значит, тяжелый участок в вашем коде - не тот который вы думаете, только и всего.

Comment: @ИльяПроняшин: Много потоков — это такое дело, вопрос в том, как между ними разделена работа.

Comment: @ИльяПроняшин: Попробуйте спрофилировать.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь средствами анализа производительности чтобы найти где затык. Пока что по описанию похоже что тормозит сам график.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

- Что показывает **Environment.ProcessorCount**?
- Какой SP на XP?
- Настройки электропитания на максимуме?
- [Это обновление пробовали?](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/896256/computers-that-are-running-windows-xp-service-pack-2-and-that-are-equipped-with-multiple-processors-that-support-processor-power-management-features-may-experience-decreased-performance)

Начинать, в любом случае, стоит с обновления самой ОС. Пробуйте обновиться с "Центра обновления Windows". Если Вы не в курсе - MS прекратила поддержку Win XP еще в 2009 году (расширенную поддержку - в 2014).

p.s. не хватает репутации для комментария.

Comment: Через msconfig пробовал отключать/включать ЦП (их максимум 4 логических, ну стандартно), пробовал что пишут в интернете, менял приоритеты потоков в программе, менял приоритет самого процесса, менял исполняющие ядра в диспетчере - ничего не помогает. Я не пойму, это я так плохо программу написал или это Intel Atom имеет какие-то особенные характеристики, или это Win XP??

Comment: @ИльяПроняшин, в Windows вытесняющая многозадачность. Ничего не надо шаманить самому, особеннов в .NET-е, где за распределение потоков по ядрам отвечает сама CLR. Дело тут скорее всего в ОС, пробуйте обновить ее.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)))